# Group by, SUM and many more (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, join, sum

On the Microsoft SQL, how to I do the following:

Company X has 3 invoices in the DB. X has type 1 of invoice and VAT 19%.
Company Y has 5 invoices in the DB. Y has type 2 of invoice and VAT 5%.

Company X example:
Type: 1, NameOfCompany: X,  BaseOfVAT: 19, Tax1: 1500, Tax2: 2000, Tax3: 3500
Type: 1, NameOfCompany: X,  BaseOfVAT: 19, Tax1: 1000, Tax2: 1000, Tax3: 3500
Type: 2, NameOfCompany: X,  BaseOfVAT: 19, Tax1: 1500, Tax2: 1000, Tax3: 3500
Company Y example:
Type: 2, NameOfCompany: Y,  BaseOfVAT: 5, Tax1: 1200, Tax2: 2100, Tax3: 100
Type: 2, NameOfCompany: Y,  BaseOfVAT: 5, Tax1: 1500, Tax2: 2000, Tax3: 500
Type: 1, NameOfCompany: Y,  BaseOfVAT: 5, Tax1: 1500, Tax2: 2000, Tax3: 500
Each of the 2 companies has many different invoices. 
How do I sum up to look like this:

Type: 1, NameOfCompany: X,  BaseOfVAT: 19, Tax1: 2500, Tax2: 3000, Tax3: 7000(this has the sum of everything of the Type:1 BUT not from certain COLUMNS like BaseOfVAT and Type:1)
Type: 2, NameOfCompany: X,  BaseOfVAT: 19, Tax1: 1500, Tax2: 2000, Tax3: 3500

Type: 2, NameOfCompany: Y,  BaseOfVAT: 5, Tax1: 2700, Tax2: 4100, Tax3: 600
(this has the sum of everything of the Type:2 BUT not from certain COLUMNS like BaseOfVAT and Type:2)
TYPE: 1, NameOfCompany: Y,  BaseOfVAT: 5, Tax1: 1500, Tax2: 2000, Tax3: 3500

In a nutshell:

Sum up everything except some columns, group them by company and BaseOfVAT and Type, Join the results into a Temp Table. I hope I was explicit enough.

If not, please excuse me, I will reformulate when I will have less hours of continous

Comment: Sample data is best served as DDL and DML statements, and example results as table markdown or well formatted `text`. I, and I suspect others, will struggle to understand that sample.

Answer (score 0):

You should use all the grouping columns in a GROUP BY statement. Try this:

```
SELECT Type, NameOfCompany, BaseOfVAT, SUM(Tax1), SUM(Tax2), SUM(Tax3)
FROM table1
GROUP BY Type, NameOfCompany, BaseOfVAT

UNION ALL

SELECT Type, NameOfCompany, BaseOfVAT, SUM(Tax1), SUM(Tax2), SUM(Tax3)
FROM table2
GROUP BY Type, NameOfCompany, BaseOfVAT;
```

This is for situation when Company X data and Company Y data are in different tables.

**UPD**

If companies are in the same table and you need to insert values to another table then try this:

```
INSERT INTO #temptable (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6) -- use real column names with correct order
SELECT Type, NameOfCompany, BaseOfVAT, SUM(Tax1), SUM(Tax2), SUM(Tax3)
FROM table
GROUP BY Type, NameOfCompany, BaseOfVAT
```

Comment: The companies are in the same table, and the sums should go into other table with different column names. Like the Tax1 total will go to Tax1Total column. But appreciate the answer

Comment: @Stefan3D I improved my answer after your response. Check it.
Please mark it as a solution if I am right.